# Comet programming and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, javascript, comet

i want to push data to user browser if an event happens on browser. with commet programming we can do this. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29

are any good tutorials available  on net??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try [PokeIn](http://pokein.codeplex.com) comet ajax library for ASP.NET

Answer (score 2):

Check out [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync), a full comet server for .NET.

There are lots of [tutorials](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/support/tutorials) available too.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a lot of Comet related projects on GitHub: http://github.com/search?q=comet&type=Repositories&x=0&y=0.  I don't see any that are ASP.NET or C#, but you can get an idea of how things work from the other implementations.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best place to start is [the Ajax Patterns page on Comet](http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming). Also, you might want to have a look at [Dojo's CometD project](http://cometd.org/). I've been playing with comet a bit, but there are some browser (as well as server) bugs that makes it inherently difficult, along with the fact that comet is directly opposite to the intended usage of HTTP (client sends request, server responds).

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source ASP.NET comet implementation called [aspComet](https://github.com/nmosafi/aspcomet) on GitHub. The solution comes with a sample chat project you could check out to get started.